# JPQL, is it possible to make a children collection of the object im selecting distinct?

Tags: java, jpql

I have the following JPQL query:

```
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project JOIN FETCH project.employees employee JOIN FETCH project.order ord " +
          "JOIN FETCH ord.customer JOIN FETCH project.defaultDailyEntrySettings LEFT JOIN FETCH employee.projectEmployeeRoles role " +
          "LEFT JOIN FETCH role.project roleProject LEFT JOIN FETCH roleProject.defaultDailyEntrySettings " +
          "WHERE project.id = :id")
Project test(@Param("id") long id);
```

The problem is that it returns duplicate employees inside `project.employees`. For every role inside `employee.projectEmployeeRoles` the employee has, it appears once in the `project.employees` list. That is caused by `JOIN FETCH employee.projectEmployeeRoles role`. So if the employee has 7 roles, it will appear 7 times in the `project.employees` list. Is there a way to make `project.employees` distinct or is there any other way to make sure that an employee only appears once in the list? I could remove the duplicates in java, but it would be better if the query doesn´t return any duplicates in the first place.

If i remove `LEFT JOIN FETCH` the result is correct and doesnt contain any duplicate employees. But the problem here is that `employee.projectEmployeeRoles` are fetched lazily for every employee which causes too much performance problems.

**Edit:**

Im using JPA with hibernate. Here is the definition of the connections of the mentioned entites:

Project:

```
@Data
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_projects",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  )
  private List<Employee> employees;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<ProjectEmployeeRole> projectEmployeeRoles;

  // more fields
}
```

Employee:

```
@Data
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_projects",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
  )
  private List<Project> projects;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_roles",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  )
  private Set<ProjectEmployeeRole> projectEmployeeRoles;

  // more fields
}
```

Role:

```
public class ProjectEmployeeRole {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @NotNull
  private Project project;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_roles",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  private List<Employee> employees;

  // more fields
```

**Edit2:**

I load one collection at a time now and im able to avoid both n+1 requests and the cartesian product. I also dont have any duplicates anymore:

Service:

```
Project project = projectRepository.findProjectInOneRequestById(id);
project.setEmployees(employeeRepository.findIneOneRequestByEmployees(project.getEmployees()));
```

Queries:

```
 @Query("SELECT project FROM Project project LEFT JOIN FETCH project.employees employee JOIN FETCH project.order ord " +
          "JOIN FETCH ord.customer LEFT JOIN FETCH project.defaultDailyEntrySettings " +
          "WHERE project.id = :id")
  Project findProjectInOneRequestById(@Param("id") long id);

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT employee FROM Employee employee LEFT JOIN FETCH employee.projectEmployeeRoles role " +
          "LEFT JOIN FETCH role.project roleProject WHERE employee IN :employees")
  List<Employee> findIneOneRequestByEmployees(@Param("employees") List<Employee> employees);
```

Comment: Which persistence provider are you using and what are the collection types in your entities' relationships? If possible provide the mapping confoguration.

Comment: @LeonardoCruz i edited my original post and provided more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible when you do not use JOIN FETCH as you have noticed. It seems that in your case Hibernate is generating a cartesian product as result of your query.
I noticed that you are using a Set in private `Set<ProjectEmployeeRole> projectEmployeeRoles;`. If you change it to a List, probably you get a MultipleBagFetchException.
I guess you had this problem before and are trying to fix it using a Set, but the consequence is that now you have a cartesian product.

I would suggest you to evaluate if you really need a JOIN FETCH here. In order to undertand the cartesian problem with Hibernate and also how to deal with MultipleBagFetchException I would suggest these articles:

[MultipleBagFetchException](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/)

[Cartesian Product - Hibernate](https://allaroundjava.com/hibernate-cartesian-product-problem/)

Comment: Ye, i switched to a set, because i got the `MultipleBagFetchException`. The problem is that i think i need to use JOIN FETCH, because if the `projectEmployeeRoles` are laziliy loaded, it will result in N+1 requests to the database which will be slow, espacially in my case because the round trip time to the database is a bit higher. So i really have to minimize the requests i send to the database. Im not sure whether the cartesian product or n+1 requests are the bigger performance problem.

Comment: From what ive read in the second article, it seems like the 2 options i mentioned above are the only 2 options. So i either have a cartesian product(which probably becomes a huge problem with more data) or i will have n+1 requests, because of lazy fetching. Is there really no alternative?

Comment: And the first article suggests fetching each collection in a seperate query. But im not sure whether that works if my collections arent all direct childs of the same parent. The collection `employees` is a child of `Project` and the collection `projectEmployeeRoles` is a child of an `employee`.

Comment: Okay, i managed to avoid both the n+1 problem and the cartesian product thanks to the first article. I posted another edit which shows the solution. But if i wanted to get a list of projects now, would there be a way to avoid n+1 requests? Because i would have to do one request to get all projects and fetch its employees and then a request for every project to fetch its employees projectEmployeeRoles.

Comment: I guess i could do some tricky stuff.  For example, do the first request to get a list of projects and fetch the employees. Add all employees of every project in a temporary list(or set to avoid duplicates). Do one request which fetches the roles of all employees inside the list and split the combined employees, after they fetched their roles, up into the projects they belong to again. So it would basically be the same 2 queries as the ones i posted above(just one which returns a list of projects instead of one project) and some additional combine/split up logic.